# Make WIN10 command line propagate WSL colors

Tags: windows, cmd, colors, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

Whenever I open my command prompt, and use the sequence of commands

```
wsl

ls
```

The output is nicely colored.

However, if I do the same in one command,

```
wsl ls
```

The output is not colored at all.

Is there some setting I am missing? Is it even possible to make the output inherit the WSL colors?
[image: demonstration]

Using WSL2 and Windows10 build 19041.867

Comment: Hi Derevin, and Welcome to Stack Overflow. Jus a heads-up that one of the main criteria for questions on this site is that they be regarding *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems."* You have a good question, but it would likely be better suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com).

Comment: Have to say, though, that my system defaults to working the way you want.  I'm not sure why (yet), but I'd be happy to follow-up more if you want to request that the question be moved to Super User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With cmd console, `ls` detects it as a non ANSI color capable terminal output and thus disables by default colored output. On Windows 10, cmd console are ANSI's color sequences capable, so you can force `ls` to color its output in that case with :

`wsl ls --color=always`

**EDIT:** An another way could be to add a terminfo entry for Windows console that include VT capabilities (see `tic`, `toe`, `terminfo`). That need some research, but this way will give colored output for every wsl commands under Windows console.

There is an existing entry for Windows ANSI console in the WSL terminfo database :

```sh
$ toe -a | grep Windows
ansi-nt         Microsoft Windows NT console POSIX ANSI mode
```

```sh
$ infocmp ansi-nt
#       Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /usr/share/terminfo/a/ansi-nt
ansi-nt|psx_ansi|Microsoft Windows NT console POSIX ANSI mode,
        am, bw, msgr,
        cols#80, it#8, lines#25,
        bel=^G, clear=\E[2J, cr=\r, cub1=^H, cud1=\n, cuf1=\E[C,
        cup=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dH, cuu1=\E[A, ed=\E[J, el=\E[K,
        home=\E[H, ht=^I, ind=\E[S, kbs=^H, kcub1=\E[D, kcud1=\E[V,
        kcuf1=\E[C, kcuu1=\E[A, nel=\r\E[S, rc=\E[u, rev=\E[7m,
        ri=\E[T, rmso=\E[m, sc=\E[s, sgr0=\E[0m, smso=\E[7m,
```

It seems we just have to add colors#8 to it for Windows 10. So many years since i last  use `tic`, i have to go through test&trials for that.

Comment: Thanks! `--color=always` is exactly what I was missing.